# Golang dynamic number of bind variables

Tags: mysql, go

I've been working with [MyMySQL](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql) and currently have written an API call that takes a variable number of parameters and generates a search query.  I have been trying to bind the passed in parameters to protect against SQL injection, however I cannot seem to figure out how to handle a variable amount of parameters.  The Bind function signature looks like:

```
Bind(params ...interface{})
```

Although I guessed both solutions wouldn't work, I tried binding each parameter one at a time in a loop, and then also tried passing in a []interface{} containing all of the parameter values.

Is there anyway to handle this solution?  Struct binding wont work since I could have multiple values per each field.  For instance, I could have 1 or 10 company IDs passed back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt was close to success. Build a, say `var foo []interface{}` containing all arguments and pass it as

```
Bind(foo...)
```

See also [Passing arguments to ... parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)